# HTML marquee ticker for long text

Tags: javascript, html, css-animations

I want to make a long text which does not fit in a div to move from left to right without, but the maximum possible portion of the text should be shown at every time.

Markup:

```
<div class="marquee" style="width:10px">my long text here/div>
```

Behavior:

```
|my long text|
|y long text |
| long text h|
|long text he|
|ong text her|
|ng text here|
```

wait and change direction

```
|ong text her|
|long text he|
| long text h|
|y long text |
|my long text|
```

repeat infinite...

I was not able to achieve this with depracted html marquee tags but it should be possible with css animations?

**I do not want to have a situation like this:**

```
|           m|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with css translations and calc():

```css
/* Make it a marquee */
.marquee {
    width:40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: right;
}

.marquee span {
    display: inline-block;
    animation-name: marquee;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-direction: reverse;

}

/* Make it move */
@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0px)
    }


    40%, 60% {
        transform: translateX(calc(40px - 100%))
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(0px)
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee "><span>my long text here</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample how you can do, and by setting the delay and duration you control the space between the texts

```css
.marquee {
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: 100%;
  animation: marquee 8s linear infinite;
}
.marquee:hover span {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.marquee span:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
.marquee span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}
.marquee span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 1.6s;
}
.marquee span:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 2.4s;
}
.marquee span:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 3.2s;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0%   { left: 100%; }
  100% { left: -100%; }
}
```

```html
<p class="marquee">
  <span>this is a</span>
  <span>this is a</span>
  <span>this is a</span>
  <span>this is a</span>
</p>
```

Comment: this includes thew situation which I do not want: |           m|

Comment: Did you visit this link https://codepen.io/Jaskaranbir/pen/JKNgrb I think this will be help full to you

Comment: this is also another behaviour

Comment: I think you have to use multiple <span>/<div> inside the marquee then only you can archive this